# Does infinity have any practical application in Physics?

Tags: mathematics, singularities

Does infinity have any practical application in Physics? I know the concept of infinity is used in mathematics, but I am not sure if we could do away with the concept of infinity in mathematics and still be able to model everything we are currently able to model. What are some of the things we can't model without it, and are those models proven without a shadow of a doubt to be models that describe "real" physical phenomena or do they describe speculative physical concepts such as string theory?

Comment: What does it mean to go without the concept of infinity in the first place? What mathematical concepts are you saying that we lose without it?

Comment: Also, what constitutes a "real" physical phenomenon? As far as I can tell, what you actually mean is "models that have demonstrated their usefulness in making predictions about the real world" (based on your contrast to "speculative physical concepts"). For example, no real object exactly follows Ohm's Law under all conditions, yet Ohm's Law is not by any means a "speculative physical concept", as electrical engineering could not exist without it.

Answer (score 2):

Infinity is pervasive throughout mainstream physics: infinite space, infinite time, infinitely small point particles, infinitely large self-energy of point particles, etc. The mathematics of quantum electrodynamics assumes that “virtual particles” can have infinite energy and momentum, and this theory is in agreement with experiment to better than one part in a trillion on some measurements, after certain problematic infinities are dealt with by a process called [renormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization).